# 404 not found error in amazon ec2 ubuntu server

Tags: laravel, amazon-ec2, http-status-code-404

Login and register button is not working properly. Please help me.

php artisan make:auth used for the authentication

This is the error

Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at www.rsktechnologies.tk Port 80

Comment: I think there is a issue of htaccess file,please check it

Comment: but i don't know how to find this error. Please tell me how to change the error

Comment: i find the error 
thanks for answering my questions

Comment: mark it  correct than other Developer  will  also   get help from there

Answer (score 0):

> add this .htaccess access file to your root

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ server.php

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. In addition to posting code as answer, please include explanations as to why this should solve the problem.